# Test fails when mocking Hibernate's SessionFactory using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

Ok, so heres the code

Test runs with MockitoJUnitRunner and in `@Before` method I execute

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

@Test
public void verifyTimestampTest(){
    TargetHistoryPK tHistoryPK = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryPK.class);

    targetHistoryDAO = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryDAOimpl.class);        
    session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
    sessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);

    Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);

    TargetHistory th = Mockito.mock(TargetHistory.class);
    Mockito.when(session.save(th)).thenReturn(tHistoryPK);

    boolean h = targetHistoryDAO.addTargetHistory(th);

    System.out.println("erh: "+ th.getTarget_update() + h);
    assertNotNull("Timestamp is null", th.getTarget_update());
}
```

and tested method

```
public class TargetHistoryDAOimpl implements TargetHistoryDAO {


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public TargetHistoryDAOimpl() {     
    }

    public TargetHistoryDAOimpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean addTargetHistory(TargetHistory th) {

        if(th.getTarget_update() == null){
            Date now = new Date();
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
            th.setTarget_update(timestamp);
        }
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        TargetHistoryPK pk = (TargetHistoryPK)session.save(th);
        if(pk != null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

Normally `addTargetHistory()` is being called from a service class method presented below

```
    @Transactional
    public boolean registerTargetActivity(TargetHistory th) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return targetHistoryDao.addTargetHistory(th);
    }
```

Can someone explain to me why my test `verifyTimestampTest()` fails?

**EDIT** I added a line to the test(I cant debug - getting sts error when trying to debug)

```
if(th == null)
        System.out.println("rggrgr");
```

like this

```
@Test
public void verifyTimestampTest(){
    TargetHistoryPK tHistoryPK = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryPK.class);
    targetHistoryDAO = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryDAOimpl.class);        
    session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
    sessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);

    Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);

    TargetHistory th = new TargetHistory();
    Mockito.when(session.save(th)).thenReturn(tHistoryPK);

    boolean h = targetHistoryDAO.addTargetHistory(th);

    if(th == null)
        System.out.println("targetHistory is null!");

    System.out.println("erh: "+ th.getTarget_update() + h);
    assertNotNull("Timestamp is null", th.getTarget_update());


}
```

and i get sts warning "Dead code". Why???? Why dead code?

Comment: The println after *if(th == null)* is dead code because *th* is never null. You always instantiate *TargetHistory th = new TargetHistory()* before that.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your *TargetHistory th* is a mock. You don't setup any behaviours for that mock's methods. That's why they do nothing and return null. On [this Mockito documentation page](http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) it says:

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).
>
> Beware that void methods on mocks do nothing by default!

You need to replace the TargetHistory mock with a real object or a stub.

Comment: Hi! I repleaced mock with real object but test still fails. I also repleaced TargetHistoryPK . PS I just edited my question.

Comment: Does it simply fail at the assertNotNull line, or is there a stacktrace involved? Can you confirm that the *if(th.getTarget_update() == null)* block code gets executed when the test is ran? What is the output of the *System.out.println("erh: "+ th.getTarget_update() + h)*?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out that the problem was with

```
targetHistoryDAO = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryDAOimpl.class);
```

I clearly didnt properly understood what a mock is.
Mockito never really calls

```
targetHistoryDAO.addTargetHistory(th);
```

I needed to add a line

```
Mockito.when(targetHistoryDAO.addTargetHistory(th)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

before calling this method. So the final code looks like this

```
    TargetHistoryPK tHistoryPK = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryPK.class);
    targetHistoryDAO = Mockito.mock(TargetHistoryDAOimpl.class);        
    session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
    sessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);

    Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);

    TargetHistory th = new TargetHistory();
    Mockito.when(session.save(th)).thenReturn(tHistoryPK);
    Mockito.when(targetHistoryDAO.addTargetHistory(th)).thenCallRealMethod();
    boolean h = targetHistoryDAO.addTargetHistory(th);
    assertNotNull("Timestamp is null", th.getTarget_update());
```

Comment: Right, targetHistoryDAO is your "system under test". I didn't notice you made a mock out of it. But then my question would be: why mock the targetHistoryDAO at all? In your test, the targetHistoryDAO should be the real thing, not a mock. If you don't mock it, you won't need *thenCallRealMethod()*.

So, in the end it is confirmed that your problem rose from the fact that "void methods on mocks do nothing by default".

Comment: I mocked it because I didn't understand what a mock really is. Terrible mistake of mine. I was bored and unfortunetly started using mockito without reading any tutorial but with some minor knowledge of it.